# TensorFlow, Keras. Build model with Boolean array as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to machine learning and just learning. TensorFlow seems easy to understand and have simple examples. But I can't find how to build model that can take boolean array(0 and 1) as input. In all examples that I found, input is array of numbers bigger than 1. Can anyone please show me how to build model with 100 boolean input layer and 1 output. Or at least tell me where to search for solution.

**EDIT**

My code:

```
array = []
with open("C:/temp/out.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        array.append(list(map(int, list(line.rstrip('\n')))))

train_data = array[:2000]
test_data = array[2000:4000]
train_labels = [1] * 2000
test_labels = [1] * 2000

# Array for prediction check
check_data = array[4000:4010] # 10 correct inputs
check_data.append([0] * 100) # Incorrect data
check_data.append([1] * 100) # Incorrect data

# Converting to numpy array
check_data = np.asarray(check_data)
train_data = np.asarray(train_data)
test_data = np.asarray(test_data)
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels)
test_labels = np.asarray(test_labels)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(80))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_data,
                    train_labels,
                    epochs=2)
results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)

predict = model.predict(check_data)
```

Summary:

```
Total params: 19,821
Trainable params: 19,821
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Fit history:

```
Epoch 1/2

  32/2000 [..............................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.1560 - acc: 0.9688
1664/2000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0039 - acc: 0.9994 
2000/2000 [==============================] - 0s 120us/step - loss: 0.0033 - acc: 0.9995

Epoch 2/2

  32/2000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7940e-07 - acc: 1.0000
1696/2000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.6042e-07 - acc: 1.0000
2000/2000 [==============================] - 0s 30us/step - loss: 2.5141e-07 - acc: 1.0000
```

Evaluate:

```
  32/2000 [..............................] - ETA: 2s
2000/2000 [==============================] - 0s 38us/step
[6.117830600942398e-07, 1.0]
```

Predict:

```
[[0.9999987 ]
 [0.9999964 ]
 [0.99999917]
 [0.9999995 ]
 [0.99999833]
 [1.        ]
 [1.        ]
 [1.        ]
 [0.9999993 ]
 [0.9999999 ]
 [0.5781495 ]
 [1.        ]]
```

As you can see only 100 zeros shows as not correct, but 100 ones(last incorrect input) is solid 1. Can anyone please show me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you try just training a model with boolean inputs? Like just numbers 0 or 1?

Comment: Is it really boolean (True/False) or integer (0/1) values? In the latter case, you can use those as features right away. Using binary input features is very convenient for DNNs (so, dense hidden layers).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, I have tried and get accuracy 1 in just few inputs, which is clearly wrong. And confirms that it's wrong when I run model.predict

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko I have tried with (0/1), but I can convert it to (True/False) if it will help. But what type of input layer should I use? Simple Dense layer or something else? And what kind of activation?

Comment: Please add details of what exactly is wrong, getting accuracy of 100% is not wrong by itself, maybe you mean overfitting?

Comment: As I understood correctly model.evaluate should show overfitting, but I get accuracy of 1 on evaluation. Another thing, that I have mostly positive data and just little list of wrong data to teach model. I think maybe that's why model predicts almost any input as 1.

Answer (score 2):

So, I tried the above code with randomly generated data. Instead of 1's and 0's its 10's and 11's

```
    array=np.round(np.random.rand(4010,100))+10 #change in data
    train_data = array[:2000]
    test_data = array[2000:4000]
    train_labels = [1] * 2000
    test_labels = [1] * 2000
    # Array for prediction check
    check_data = [list(item) for item in array[4000:4010]] # 10 correct inputs
    check_data.append([10] * 100) # Incorrect data
    check_data.append([11] * 100) # Incorrect data

Predicted Output:

    array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

So, from this you can infer that 0 is taken at face value.

In neural networks, each neuron solves the equation y=wx+b

where y: output of neuron, w=weights,x =input to the neuron, b=bias

When x=0, y=b and x=1, y=w+b

Therefore, whenever the input is 0, the neuron is almost switched off (bias values     are generally very small)

The model does not learn that all 0's and all 1's are wrong data. The output for all 0's is coincidentally right and the output for all 1's tells us its a coincidence and something is wrong.

Also, your data has 0's and 1's in it with label 1 attached to it. You cannot expect to give all 1's and all 0's and expect the model to predict it as wrong data.

Comment: For now I have only data that is correct and should output 1(true). How I can tell to model to find pattern in data that I have and use this pattern in prediction? Do I have to convert 0's and 1's to some number like you did? I was hopping tensorFlow has some preprocessing method to that, but I didn't found it.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to do what you want with this data. It is like learning simple addition and then trying to solve statistics problem. You know what the numbers are and all you have learnt to do is randomly add the numbers.This will give you some answer but the chances of it being right are very low. I would advice you to get better data. Always remember that the model is only as good as it's data.

Comment: It's seems I misunderstood whole concept of neural networks. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found it helpful, would you be kind enough to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your labels:

```
train_labels = [1] * 2000
test_labels = [1] * 2000
```

It's all 1's, everything is 1.

Of course your model will predict 1 and only 1.

You must train your model with correct data.

Comment: For now I have only data that is correct and should output 1(true). How I can tell to model to find pattern in data that I have and use this pattern in prediction?

Comment: You must have data. It's impossible to train a model without data.

Comment: As you can see in my code I have data array 'train_data' for training and
'test_data' for evaluation. Also small check_data for prediction test. All data is 2 dimensional arrays with arrays of 0's and 1's. Or you mean something else?

Comment: You don't have a single example with result 0. Your model will never learn result 0. Neural networks seem intelligent, but they are just memorizers. It will never learn something it never saw.

Comment: It's seems I misunderstood whole concept of neural networks. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Well...maybe I exagerated here.... they can get pretty intelligent, but they need enough examples of all types of outputs.

Comment: If they can't find pattern or dependencies in data, then it's not what I was looking for. At least now I know that.

Comment: They can, but you need examples first for training.

Comment: I have examples(about 100 000), but as I said I have only data that is correct(true). I was using just small amount of data to test if it even works at all. In my understanding to find correct pattern you need only correct data.

Comment: If you have only correct data your model will learn that anything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

def generate_data(n_samples):
    X = np.zeros((n_samples,100))
    y = np.zeros((n_samples))

    for i in range(n_samples):
        X[i] = np.random.randint(0,2,100)
        r = xor(X[i])
        y[i] = xor(X[i])
    return X, y

def xor(a):
    b = np.array(a,dtype=bool)
    r = b[0]
    for x in b[1:]:
        r = r ^x
    return int(r)

X, y = generate_data(1000)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

## Train data

- We are generating a random array of size 100 of only 0'(False) and
  1's (Trues). These are the samples (X's a we call in ML)
- The label/target of the sample is the logical XOR of the sample. (called y in ML). As you can the the possible label values are 1 and 0 which makes it a binary classification problem

## Model

A simple NN of 3 layers with 100 neurons in 1's layer, 8 neurons in second layer and 1 neuron in last layer.We have choosen 1 neuron in the last layer because we have 2 classes and we are using sigmoid activation so the last neuron > 0.5 we will assign the sample to class 1 else to class 0

Then we train the model using binary crossentropy loss using adam optimizer for 150 epochs.